# Box shadow on css triangle

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, box-shadow

I have a few list elements that has a css triangle arrow after them. I'd like to add `box-shadow` around the arrow, but can't figure out why my shadow isn't working. I have tried following other solutions, but those solutions use `::after` pseudo element to make the triangle, but my triangle is a separate `div`. any help is much appreciated.

```css
#shippingsteps li {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 35px;
  background: #ececec;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#shippingsteps li a {
  color: #4A4947
}
#shippingsteps li span {
  background: #7c7a7b;
  color: white;
}
#shippingsteps li.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold
}
#shippingsteps li.active a {
  color: white;
}
#shippingsteps li.active span {
  background: #C60001;
  color: white;
  border-color: #C60001
}
#shippingsteps li::after {
  border: none;
}
#shippingsteps li .nav-arrow {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ececec;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 31px 0 30px 20px;
  ;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -19px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 150;
}
#shippingsteps li .nav-arrow::after {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ececec;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 31px 0 30px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: -32px;
  transform: rotate(31deg);
  z-index: 100;
}
#shippingsteps li.active .nav-arrow {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix" id="shippingsteps">
  <li class="first active">
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <span>1</span><a data-target="checkout_login" href="#">
        Checkout Method </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <span>2</span><a data-target="billing_shipping" href="#">
        Billing &amp; Shipping</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <span>3</span><a data-target="order_review" href="#">
        Your Order &amp; Payment</a>
  </li>
  <li><span>4</span><a href="#">
        Confirmation</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS: Trying to put shadow around the grey triangles, the black one doesn't need any.

Comment: You know the box-shadow will be a rectangle..right?

Comment: like mentioned above box shadow puts a shadow around the box regardless of whether you have manipulated borders to create a triangle, they still exist in a box.

Comment: Will the triangles change at all? I would suggest using an image instead.

Comment: Paulie, yes, that's my problem, the rectangular box shadow. rotating isn't helping me to get the shadow in position. 

Hieu, don't want to use an image unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: You'll need a trick like this https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Comment: tried it already. not working.

Answer (score 6):

As previously answered in [CSS box shadow around a custom shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855529/css-box-shadow-around-a-custom-shape) , you want to use the property `filter:drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5))` with all vendor prefixes.

Comment: didn't know about this! How's the browser support for this filter? Any way to use a fallback for IE?

Comment: An awful looking `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, 
Color='#444')";`