# How to give Shadow on image

Tags: css

Image with Shadow Effect,This is JPG Image,
[image]

Here Is png image where create shadow:
[image]

My Code Is :

```css
img.image-shadow {
   box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="image-shadow" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtIqi.png">
 </body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this to add shadow below your image,

```
img{
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,225,0.6));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,225,0.6));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,225,0.6)); 
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,225,0.6));
 filter: drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,225,0.6)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `drop-shadow` property instead of `box-shadow`

http://bricss.net/post/33158273857/box-shadow-vs-filter-drop-shadow

This is also covered in a previous SO article:

[CSS box shadow around a custom shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855529/css-box-shadow-around-a-custom-shape)

Note that it's not widely supported, yet there are other methods for achieving what you want in the SO link.

Comment: No problem. I noticed @frnt posted his/her answer sooner than I did, however I'll leave mine here due to the links.

Comment: Waw ! Impressive !

Answer (score -2):

<s>You would have to use some kind of online tool that creates an SVG grapic shape on top of your image at first and then apply the shadow on the shape.</s>

<s>I don't know such tool, but</s> you have to think about what you want to do in CSS before preparing your image in a software.